# Is it possible to prohibit axes rotation with the mouse in Mayavi?

Tags: python, mayavi

I am creating a 2-D plot using Mayavi, in order to take advantage of some of the rendering features. Since it is a 2-D (x,y) plot, placed in 3-D space, I would like restrain the mouse interaction with the plot such that the plot cannot be rotated with the mouse, only zoomed or panned. Is this possible?

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14225512/constrain-mayavi-mouse-drag-to-rotating-earth-around-its-axis), but has not been answered as yet. The code there would apply to my case as well, even though it's 3-D.

Regards,

-Mark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Via Gael Varoquaux: 
http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/tips.html#changing-the-interaction-with-a-scene

```
figure.scene.interactor.interactor_style =  tvtk.InteractorStyleImage()
```