# Changing center of rotation in a 3D plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-3d

I have a 3D line plot in matplotlib, created using the following code:

```
    def view(self):
        from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D  #noqa
        import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

        ax = plt.figure().gca(projection='3d')
        history = np.array(self.position_history)
        x, y ,z = history[:, 0], history[:, 1], history[:, 2]
        ax.plot(x, y, z)

        plt.show()
```

Here `history` is an Mx3 array of points. This works fine and pops up a plot as expected. I am able to click and drag to modify the azimuth and elevation interactively. I am able to zoom by right-clicking and dragging.

However I am wondering if it is possible to modify the center point of the pan and zoom? I would like to zoom into the top-right, and then pan around with the top right as my center of rotation. If you have ever used solidworks or another CAD program, this is the behavior I am after. Is this doable? If not interactively, can I do it programmatically?

And finally, if none of this is possible in matplotlib, is there another library that can accomplish what I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have also run into trouble in the past in terms of customizing mplot3d, rather unsuccessfully..

> And finally, if none of this is possible in matplotlib, is there another library that can accomplish what I want?

you can do this with [mayavi](http://code.enthought.com/projects/mayavi/)

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14225512/constrain-mayavi-mouse-drag-to-rotating-earth-around-its-axis) is a relevant stackoverflow answer for customizing how you interact with your plot

there are also various useful [tips and tricks](http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/tips.html) for animating in general and for using mayavi

(apologies if this isn't useful)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: I am accepting this answer because I did ask for alternatives if what I want is not possible in Matplotlib

Answer (score 4):

Not sure this will do what you need but you can define the center when you first plot.  Here, "c_x" is the center of rotation on the x axis and the -/+ 200 defines the axis to be 200 units in both direction.  Likewise for y and z.

If you had the user choose the center before plotting, that could work as a crude work around.

http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html?highlight=set_xbound#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xbound

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')    
ax.autoscale(enable=False,axis='both')  #you will need this line to change the Z-axis
ax.set_xbound(c_x-200, c_x+200)
ax.set_ybound(c_y-200, c_y+200)
ax.set_zbound(c_z-200, c_z+200)
```